# Having trouble to integrate kafka with clickhouse

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

I want to load my topic data into clickhouse, for that i am following `https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/kafka/`

I am running all the below commands in respective order, though tables created but not getting any data from my topic.

```
`CREATE TABLE COMBINED_DATA_CSV
 (
    ORDERID UInt8,
    SALENPRODUCT2_PERSONID UInt8,
    LASTNAME String,
    FIRSTNAME String,
    ADDRESS String,
    CITY String,
    SALES_DESTRUCTURED_PID UInt8,
    PNAME String,
    PRICE UInt16,
   QUANTITY UInt16
) ENGINE = Kafka()
SETTINGS
    kafka_broker_list = 'localhost:9092',
    kafka_topic_list = 'COMBINED_DATA_CSV',
    kafka_group_name = 'personproductsales',
    kafka_format = 'CSV',
    kafka_row_delimiter = ',',
    kafka_num_consumers = 1,
    kafka_skip_broken_messages = 0`


`CREATE TABLE COMBINED_DATA1_CSV (
    ORDERID UInt8,
    SALENPRODUCT2_PERSONID UInt8,
    LASTNAME String,
    FIRSTNAME String,
    ADDRESS String,
    CITY String,
    SALES_DESTRUCTURED_PID UInt8,
    PNAME String,
    PRICE UInt16,
    QUANTITY UInt16,
    sign Int8 DEFAULT 1
    ) ENGINE = CollapsingMergeTree(sign) ORDER BY ORDERID;`


`CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW DATA1 TO COMBINED_DATA1_CSV AS SELECT * from     COMBINED_DATA_CSV;`
```

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: No errors but data is not loading

Comment: Can you try to use a different `kafka_group_name`? e.g. `kafka_group_name = 'personproductsalesTEST'`

Comment: Did you check the error log? Is it empty?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous yeah i tried that, still not working

Comment: Problem is adding an extra column of sign for collpasing

Comment: its working fine when i am using mergetree engine